# *args, **kwargs in jinja2 macros

Tags: python, macros, jinja2

How are extra args & kwargs handled for a Jinja2 macro? The documentation isn't exactly clear offhand.

For example, this is clearly wrong:

```
{% macro example_1(one, two, **kwargs) %}
    do macro stuff
{% endmacro %}
```

which results in

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError

TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'name', got '**'
```

The [documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#macros) says:

> *kwargs*
>
> Like *varargs* but for keyword arguments. All unconsumed keyword arguments are stored in this special variable.

Unfortunately, any combo of extra keyword arguments is an error,

```
{% macro example_2(one, two) %}
    do macro stuff
{% endmacro %}

{{ example_2(one, two, test='test') }}

TypeError: macro 'example_2' takes no keyword keyword argument 'test'
```

I have no examples and am not poking about in the Jinja2 source code atm. The documentation isn't clear to me at this point. Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like it might not support arbitrary keyword arguments. Perhaps e.g. `{% macro example_2(one, two, test=None) %}` or similar?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The trick is that `kwargs` has to be **accessed at least once** in any macro that should accept them.  That is to say, you must call `{{ kwargs }}` once in macro body *without* declaring it in macro argument list. The same is true for `{{ varargs }}`.

This will not work

```
{% macro example_2(one, two) %}
    * {{one}} - {{two}}
{% endmacro %}
{{example_2(1, 2, test="Hello")}}
```

This will

```
{% macro example_2(one, two) %}
    * {{one}} - {{two}}
    * {{kwargs}}
{% endmacro %}
{{example_2(1, 2, test="Hello")}}
```

Comment: Wow, that is a very distasteful design choice.

Comment: @BrenBarn - I have to agree with you - there is a *lot* of awesome stuff in Jinja - the magical pseudo-globals are not of that category.

Comment: I won't claim this is *great*, but at least we can put it in a comment to get stripped out at render time `{# {{kwargs}} #}`

Comment: The comment approach didn't work for me. Might be version specific.

Comment: Do you mean I'm supposed to write `{% if False %}{{ kwargs }}{% endif %}` or the version Taylor wrote? Oh...

Comment: @SeanVieira What do you mean by: **kwargs has to be accessed at least once** ? Could you please explain more ?

Comment: @4m1nh4j1 - if you look at the *second* code snippet in my answer you'll see that I'm **using** `kwargs` - that lets me call `example_2` with "extra" arguments and not have it blow up.  The *first* code snippet does not do anything with `kwargs` and so blows up when I pass it extra arguments.  Does that make sense?

Comment: For those who the `* {{ kwargs }}` is **showing in the browser view**, this might be helpful:
You can put `* {{ kwargs }}` in an element which you can then give a **style of display none** e.g

    `<span class="d-none">* {{ kwargs }}</span> # for bootstrap`
OR

    `<span style="display:none;">* {{ kwargs }}</span>`

Comment: This `{{lwargs}}`, is it acting like a `**kwargs` works cause I have a similar situation that involves passing in much variables to be used in the template @seanvieira?

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to [Sean Viera's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13944920/8213085), the `kwargs` object will be a dictionary so if you want to use it you can iterate over it [by accessing the `items()` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25375815/8213085), like in normal Python:

```
{% macro iterate_kwargs() %}
    {% for key, value in kwargs.items() %}
    The key, {{ key }}, has a value of {{ value }}
    {%- endfor -%}
{% endmacro %}

{{ iterate_kwargs(id=123, colour="blue", size="S") }}
```

This will output the following:

```
    The key, id, has a value of 123
    The key, colour, has a value of blue
    The key, size, has a value of S
```

---

This was written and tested using [dbt](https://www.getdbt.com/) so may not be available to all tools that use Jinja