# How to iterate through a list of dictionaries in Jinja template?

Tags: python, dictionary, flask, iteration, jinja2

I tried:

```
list1 = [{"username": "abhi", "pass": 2087}]
return render_template("file_output.html", list1=list1)
```

In the template:

```
<table border=2>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Key
    </td>
    <td>
      Value
    </td>
  </tr>
  {% for dictionary in list1 %}
    {% for key in dictionary %}
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h3>{{ key }}</h3>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h3>{{ dictionary[key] }}</h3>
        </td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

The above code is splitting each element into multiple characters:

```
[

{

"

u

s

e

r

...
```

I tested the above nested loop in a simple Python script and it works fine but not in Jinja template.

Answer (score 293, accepted):

#### Data:

```py
parent_list = [{'A': 'val1', 'B': 'val2'}, {'C': 'val3', 'D': 'val4'}]
```

#### in Jinja2 iteration:

```
{% for dict_item in parent_list %}
   {% for key, value in dict_item.items() %}
      <h1>Key: {{key}}</h1>
      <h2>Value: {{value}}</h2>
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

#### Note:

Make sure you have the list of dict items. If you get `UnicodeError` may be the value inside the dict contains unicode format. That issue can be solved in your `views.py`.
If the dict is `unicode` object, you have to encode into `utf-8`.

Comment: Might be because I'm using a newer version of jinja, but in my case I had to remove the parentheses (use `dict_item.items` instead) or it would throw a `Could not parse the remainder: '()' from 'dict_item.items()'`

Comment: In addition to TrakJohnson's answer I have found that the new jinja indexes dicitonaries with `dict.key` instead of the conventional `dict["key"]`.

Comment: @TrakJohnson: then you are **not using Jinja templating**, but are instead using *Django* templates. You want to read [how to iterate through dictionary in a dictionary in django template?](//stackoverflow.com/q/8018973). Django template syntax is similar, but not the same.

Comment: @CameronHyde: Jinja, in all versions, supports both attribute and item access on all objects. See the [*Variables* section of the template documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#variables). If `dict["key"]` doesn't work for you, then you are not using Jinja templates, but Django templates. See [Accessing dictionary by key in Django template](//stackoverflow.com/q/19745091)

Comment: what if you want to use each item in the dictionary in a different way - you don't want to loop through the keys but you still want to access the keys?

Answer (score 29):

As a sidenote to @Navaneethan 's answer, `Jinja2` is able to do "regular" item selections for the list and the dictionary, given we know the key of the dictionary, or the locations of items in the list.

#### Data:

```
parent_dict = [{'A':'val1','B':'val2', 'content': [["1.1", "2.2"]]},{'A':'val3','B':'val4', 'content': [["3.3", "4.4"]]}]
```

#### in Jinja2 iteration:

```
{% for dict_item in parent_dict %}
   This example has {{dict_item['A']}} and {{dict_item['B']}}:
       with the content --
       {% for item in dict_item['content'] %}{{item[0]}} and {{item[1]}}{% endfor %}.
{% endfor %}
```

#### The rendered output:

```
This example has val1 and val2:
    with the content --
    1.1 and 2.2.

This example has val3 and val4:
   with the content --
   3.3 and 4.4.
```

Comment: how to modify that jinja2 code, if size of dict is not fixed and can change over time?

Answer (score 19):

```
{% for i in yourlist %}
  {% for k,v in i.items() %}
    {# do what you want here #}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: {% for k,v in lis1.items() %}
UndefinedError: 'unicode object' has no attribute 'items'

Comment: @user3089927 is there more to your template than you're showing us? This solution is correct. If it's not, `lis` is not a list when the code you've shared is executed.

Comment: I overlooked a thing. I had to replace double quotes in a list dictionary and when I do it, it obviously converts the list of dictionary into string. I will post other ques with the problem I am facing.

Answer (score 0):

Just a side note for similar problem (If we don't want to loop through):

> How to lookup a dictionary using a variable key within Jinja template?

Here is an example:

```
{% set key = target_db.Schema.upper()+"__"+target_db.TableName.upper() %}
{{ dict_containing_df.get(key).to_html() | safe }}
```

It might be obvious. But we don't need curly braces within curly braces. Straight python syntax works. (I am posting because I was confusing to me...)

Alternatively, you can simply do

```
{{dict[target_db.Schema.upper()+"__"+target_db.TableName.upper()]).to_html() | safe }}
```

But it will spit an error when no key is found. So better to use `get` in Jinja.

Answer (score 0):

```
**get id from dic value. I got the result.try the below code**
get_abstracts = s.get_abstracts(session_id)
    sessions = get_abstracts['sessions']
    abs = {}
    for a in get_abstracts['abstracts']:
        a_session_id = a['session_id']
        abs.setdefault(a_session_id,[]).append(a)
    authors = {}
    # print('authors')
    # print(get_abstracts['authors'])
    for au in get_abstracts['authors']: 
        # print(au)
        au_abs_id = au['abs_id']
        authors.setdefault(au_abs_id,[]).append(au)
 **In jinja template**
{% for s in sessions %}
          <h4><u>Session : {{ s.session_title}} - Hall : {{ s.session_hall}}</u></h4> 
            {% for a in abs[s.session_id] %}
            <hr>
                      <p><b>Chief Author :</b>  Dr. {{ a.full_name }}</p>  
               
                {% for au in authors[a.abs_id] %}
                      <p><b> {{ au.role }} :</b> Dr.{{ au.full_name }}</p>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
```