# Access dictionary within dictionary jinja

Tags: python, html, jinja2

I have a list of dictionaries called data.
for every_archive in data I want to acces `every_archive['key1']['key2']`

First key it's a constant: "units" but the second key depends on a loop.

I have already tried : `{{ archive['units'][{{item['param']}}] }}`

where `item['param']` item is another iterator in a loop and item['param'] is the second key.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to iterate through a list of dictionaries in jinja template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25373154/how-to-iterate-through-a-list-of-dictionaries-in-jinja-template)

Answer (score 1):

See the format below! The structure is going to be very similar to how you would loop through a dictionary in Python, but with the jinja {% %} for each statement you do not want to display and {{ }} around each expression you want to display.

Taken from [How to iterate through a list of dictionaries in jinja template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25373154/how-to-iterate-through-a-list-of-dictionaries-in-jinja-template)

```
Data: parent_dict = [{'A':{'a':1}},{'B':{'b':2}},{'C':{'c':3}},{'D':{'d':4}}]
```

```
In Jinja2 iteration:
{% for dict_item in parent_dict %}
   {% for key1 in dict_item %}
      {% for key2 in dict_item[key1] %}
        <h2>Value: {{dict_item[key1][key2]}}</h2>
      {% endfor %}
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Yes, this works fine but my ```key2``` is not a string, is the value of ```item['param']```

Comment: I am not sure, I am understanding your data structure. Can you provide an example?

Comment: so I receive in HTML the variable ```data``` which contains ```item``` which is a dictionary and  I also receive ```details``` which is also a dictionary. Then I have ```{ % for elem in data['item'] %}  <p> {{ details['units'][ elem['param'] ] }} </p>```. The thing is that ```elem['param']``` is in for and I need to use it as the second key for ```details```.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, you have a list that contains some nested dictionaries; if that's the case, and your data looks like that:

```
data = [{'foo': {'bar1': 'buzz1', 'bar2': 'buzz2'}}, {'foo': {'bar3': 'buzz3', 'bar4': 'buzz4'}}]
```

if you use this Jinja2:

```
    {% for every_archive in data %} 
        {% for key1, archive1 in every_archive.items() %}
          {% for key2, value2 in archive1.items() %}
            <p>{{ key1 }} - {{ key2 }} - {{ value2 }}</p>
          {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

you will get this output:

```
foo - bar1 - buzz1

foo - bar2 - buzz2

foo - bar3 - buzz3

foo - bar4 - buzz4
```

also, the same output you will get from

```
<p>{{ key1 }} - {{ key2 }} - {{ archive1[key2] }}</p>
```