# jinja2 turning lists into strings even when from_json is being used

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am trying to run a nested `for` loop in order to retrieve a nested value.
I would like to retrieve `some_value_4` when `some_value_3` matches a criteria that's predefined.

```
{
  "some_dict": {
    "some_key_0": "value_0",
    "some_key_1": "value_1"
  },
  "testval_dict": {
    "test_key_0": "some_value_0",
    "test_key_1": "some_value_1",
    "test_key_2": "some_value_2",
    "test_key_3": "some_value_3",
    "test_key_4": "some_value_4"
  }
}
```

The playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
   
   - set_fact:
       mydict: "{{ lookup('file', '/tmp/file.json' ) | from_json }}"

   - debug:
       msg: |
            "{% for item in mydict %}
             {{ item }}
             {% endfor %}"
```

when run, it alreay looks like dict names are treated as string and nothing more:

```
ansible-playbook /tmp/test_playbook.yml -c local -i ', localhost'
TASK [debug] ******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {}

MSG:

" somee_dict
  testval_dict
 "
```

Then when I add an `itme.key` to the `debug` task, the playbook fails:

```
MSG:

The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'str object' has no attribute 'value'
```

Thank you.

**edit for clarification**
In the real example, I will not know the names of the dicts, so I cannot use `some_dict` or `testval_dict`, that is why I'm trying to go over this data source in an `item.key` or `item.value` form.

Comment: thank you. yes I don't have the conditionals as I wasn't even being successful with getting into the next level down the dict whatsoever, so I kept the question simple. :) I am able to do so using your example. I cannot treat this in a form of `{{item.key}}` or `{{item.value}}`, am I doomed here and jinja2 will keep only getting strings ?

Comment: Re-adding my previous comment. You should be able to access the values of `testval_dict` by `mydict.testval_dict.test_key_X` without looping.

Comment: I quite foolishly edit a comment left by another user :(, the advice was to use `mydict.testval_dict` in order get one level further in the dict.

Comment: sorry about that @seshadri_c , I didn't have enough coffee yet, obviously.

Comment: @seshadri_c, I think I have to loop here, as I _do not_ know what would be the name of either of dicts, so I must ignore them and iterate within them, does that make sense ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: **"*{% for item in mydict %} ... dict names are treated as string and nothing more.*"**

A: This is correct. A dictionary, when evaluated as a list, returns the list of its keys. See some examples below

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ mydict.keys()|list }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ mydict[item] }}"
      loop: "{{ mydict.keys()|list }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ mydict|difference(['testval_dict']) }}"
```

give

```yaml
  msg:
  - some_dict
  - testval_dict
```

```yaml
  msg:
    some_key_0: value_0
    some_key_1: value_1

  msg:
    test_key_0: some_value_0
    test_key_1: some_value_1
    test_key_2: some_value_2
    test_key_3: some_value_3
    test_key_4: some_value_4
```

```yaml
  msg:
  - some_dict
```

See [How to iterate through a list of dictionaries in Jinja template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25373154/how-to-iterate-through-a-list-of-dictionaries-in-jinja-template)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to loop over the dictionary, you can use `with_dict` loop functionality. This way, if you loop over `mydict` and get `item.key` you will get `somee_dict` and `testval_dict`.

```yaml
  tasks:
  - set_fact:
      mydict: "{{ lookup('file', '/tmp/file.json')|from_json }}"
  # This will get the top level dictionaries somee_dict and testval_dict
  - debug:
      var: item.key
    with_dict: "{{ mydict }}"
```

And if you get `item.value` of `mydict` you will get the sub-dictionary:

```yaml
  - debug:
      var: item.value
    with_dict: "{{ mydict }}"
```

Will produce (showing output only for `testval_dict`):

```
    "item.value": {
        "test_key_0": "some_value_0",
        "test_key_1": "some_value_1",
        "test_key_2": "some_value_2",
        "test_key_3": "some_value_3",
        "test_key_4": "some_value_4"
    }
```

Comment: correct, I've tried that, and it leads me to use `with_dict.testval_dict`, and then again I muse hardoce the names of the dicts. perhaps there's no escaping this and I'm trying what can't be done.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be true. As accessing values in a dictionary without knowing the keys even without nesting is quite difficult.