# how to iterate a dictionary of list in jinja

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

i have a dictionary in jinja:

```
  reservations:
test:
  - hw_address: 00:0c:29:60:F8:3D
    ip_addresses: 2001:db8:1::101
alpine:     
  - hw_address: 00:50:56:84:F4:B2
    ip_addresses: 2001:db8:1::102        
test_server:     
  - duid: 01:02:03:04:05:06:07:08:09:0A
    ip_addresses: 2001:db8:1::103
    prefixes: 2001:db8:2:abcd::/64
    hostname: foo.example.com
```

and I would like a result similar to this

```
{ "hw-address": "00:0c:29:60:F8:3D", "ip-addresses": [ "2001:db8:1::101" ] },
{ "hw-address": "00:50:56:84:F4:B2", "ip-addresses": [ "2001:db8:1::102" ] } 
{ "duid": "01:02:03:04:05:06:07:08:09:0A",
  "ip_addresses": ["2001:db8:1::103"],
  "prefixes": ["2001:db8:2:abcd::/64"],
  "hostname": "foo.example.com"
}
```

i tried dictsort, but i can't access the items

```
        {%- for vm_name, d in reservations | dictsort %}
        {{ vm_name }}
        {{ d }}
        {% endfor %}
```

Comment: You might want to look into: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25373154/how-to-iterate-through-a-list-of-dictionaries-in-jinja-template

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to iterate through a list of dictionaries in Jinja template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25373154/how-to-iterate-through-a-list-of-dictionaries-in-jinja-template)