# Iterating through a python dictionary in flask jinja

Tags: python, dictionary, flask, iteration, jinja2

I have a dictionary which has all the country codes and the corresponding country names, a sample of it looks like this:

```
{'AF': 'Afghanistan'}
{'AL': 'Albania'}
{'DZ': 'Algeria'}
{'AD': 'Andorra'}
{'AO': 'Angola'}
```

When i followed this stack overflow question: [How to iterate through a list of dictionaries in Jinja template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25373154/how-to-iterate-through-a-list-of-dictionaries-in-jinja-template) to try and iterate through the countries I had an issue as it's not adding any elements.
This is my code:

```
{% extends "base.html" %} {% block title %}Test{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container pt-5">
      <h1 align="center">TEST PAGE</h1>
</div>
{% for dict_item in countries %}
    {% for key,value in dict_item.items %}
        <h1>Key: {{ key }}</h1>
        <h2>Value: {{ value }}</h2>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

It's not adding any headings and when i tried `dict_items.items()` (with brackets after items), I got an error of: `jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'str object' has no attribute 'items'`

I'm not too sure what's going wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

(Just incase it's useful, this is my views.py:)

```
@views.route("/test", methods=["GET"])
@login_required
def test():
    countries = Country.query.all()
    for country in countries:
        countriess = {}
        countriess[country.country_code] = country.country_name
        print(countriess)

    return render_template("TEST.html", user=current_user, countries=countriess)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing `views.py` to:

```
@views.route("/test", methods=["GET"])
@login_required
def test():
    countries = Country.query.all()
    countriess = []
    for country in countries:
        countriess.append({country.country_code: country.country_name})

    return render_template("TEST.html", user=current_user, countries=countriess)
```

This code will create a list of dictionaries `countries`, there is not need to change the templating code.

Comment: Hello, this works great, is countriess a list or dictionary?

Comment: countriess is a list of dictionaries

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I have a dropdown menu and I wanted to add all the countries to it.
```        
{% for dict_item in countries %}
        {% for key,value in dict_item.items() %}
        <div class="option">
                    <input type="radio" class="radio" id="{{ key }}" name="countries"/>
                    <label for="{{ key }}">{{ value }}</label>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
```
Could you please explain why this isn't adding anything. Might be easier to read here: https://pastebin.com/wxQmHuS7

Comment: Sorry but I cannot tell

Comment: Oh sorry I thought I replied, I made a stupid mistake but your solution works perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

in `views.py`, you set `countries=countriess` for template rendering. `countriess` is re-initialised in the `for` loop in the `test` function (countriess = {}), so the `countriess` passed along to the template is actually a `{country_code: country_name}` pair for the last country from the `countries` list.

Going back to the actual error though: when you iterate over `countries` dictionary within the template (`{% for dict_item in countries %}`), you actually iterate over keys of `countries`, which, as I said before, is `countriess` from the `views.py`, so basically you just retrieve the `country_code` of the last country from `countries`. So the dict_item is actually a string (country code), hence you get the error for `{% for key,value in dict_item.items %}`, thinking that it is actually a dictionary and not a string.

TL;DR I think that you meant to do `countries=countries` rather than `countries=countriess` in `views.py`. Then the rest of the code would make sense. (I assume the for loop with `countriess` was just for debugging?)

Comment: I tried your change and seem to have received an error: 
``jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'website.models.Country object' has no attribute 'items'``

Comment: Oh okay, it's all about the types. I thought `countries` might be a dictionary, but it is a separate Country class. In that case you indeed have to create a dictionary out of the values of `country` as you need (as suggested in the accepted answer).